# BeautifulSoup to scrape table data and store as values for future calculations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Very new to webscraping and so I appreciate all the help.  I'm trying to build a model that pulls in values from an NHL reference table found 
here:
https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2019.html#

I'm only trying to pull values pertaining to the 'Team Statistics' table which contains the aggregate team data.  I'm making some progress but I am stuck when trying to pull the row data for each team and store it for future calculations.  Here is my code so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2019.html"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")


all_stats = soup.find('div', {'id': 'all_stats'})
print(all_stats)
```

With this code I'm able to see the row information I need in HTML form but any attempt to pull that data results in finding None.  I imagine I have to assign each team and td value a variable so I can call on it in the future.  There are 30 rows of data that I need to collect.

Thanks for the help,
George

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `Team Statistics` table is in Comment line so you don't parse it.
In this case you can use `Comment` from `bs4` like :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup , Comment
from urllib import urlopen


search_url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2019.html#'

page = urlopen(search_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

table = soup.findAll('table') ## html part with no comment
table_with_comment = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in table_with_comment]
## print table_with_comment  print all comment line

for c in table_with_comment:
    a = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
    teams = a.findAll('td', attrs={'class':'left'}) # Team
    values = a.findAll('td', attrs={'class':'right'}) #stats

    for getvalues in values:

        print getvalues.text
    for gettextinElement in teams:
        print gettextinElement.text
```

**OUTPUT :**
For Stats:

```
27.1
62
47
11
4
98
.790
239
162
5
1
1.26
-0.05
6.47
172
131
61 ..UP TO END
```

For Teams :

```
Tampa Bay Lightning
Calgary Flames
Boston Bruins
San Jose Sharks
New York Islanders
Toronto Maple Leafs
Winnipeg Jets
Nashville Predators
Washington Capitals
Columbus Blue Jackets .. UP TO END
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm able to get the output like you've shown.  Could you tell me how to get this information into a usable matrix where i could run calculation?  I want the user to input two team names and then the program to run a calculation based on the statistics for the two teams.

Comment: You have to deal with it . I can just help to get datas like above . I think you can do it :) @George

Comment: Thank you Omer!

I'm having trouble figuring out how to build the pandas dataset because I'm not sure I fully understand the code you added.  Can you explain the for in statements and the get commands

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @Omer Tekbiyik's answer that will also get the data into a dataframe:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4, Comment
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2019.html#"

res= requests.get(url)
soup = bs4(res.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.findAll('table') 
table_with_comment = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
my_table = pd.read_html(table_with_comment[16])
my_table
```

The output is a dataframe with the Team Statistics table; from here you can run on it anything you can run on any pandas dataframe.

Comment: Thank you Jack!

Using Omer's method, I'm having trouble figuring out how to use my previous code for building the Pandas database... any hints would be appreciated